# Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology Bott, Tu proposition 2.3, page 23

Tags: algebraic-topology

In proving that the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is exact, at the top of page 23, the book says

**Proposition 2.3. The Mayer-Vietoris sequence is exact**

**Proof**

**The exactness is clear except at the last step. We first consider the
case of functions on $M = \mathbb{R}^1$. Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on $U \cap V$ as shown in Figure 21. We must write $f$ as the difference of a function on $U$ and a function on $V$. Let {${\rho_u, \rho_v}$} be a partition of unity subordinate to the open cover {$U, V$}. Note that $p_vf$ is a function on $U$ - to get a function on an open set we must multiply by the partition function of the other open set.**

**Since**
**$(\rho_u f)-(-\rho_v f) =f,$** 
***$$ \Omega ^0(U) \oplus \Omega ^o (V) \to \Omega ^0 (\mathbb{R}^1) $$ is surjective.***

Shouldn't it be 
*$$ \Omega ^0(U) \oplus \Omega ^o (V) \to \Omega ^0 (U \cap V) $$*

is surjective?

Note that the book at this point is using the contravarian functor $\Omega^*$ and not the covariant functor

https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf

Comment: Not everyone has that book available to them. You are more likely to receive an answer if you include a screenshot of the relevant parts from the book.

Comment: If you’re asking about something from a book, it’s good practice to post a screenshot from whatever you’re asking about, or imo better yet, to quote or paraphrase the relevant portions in your post. That way people can respond even if they don’t have a copy or the book in question on hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is a typo. You can see this in the next sentence "For a general manifold $M$, if ...´".